# WPA blocks UDP broadcast

Tags: wireless-networking, kde, udp

I use a convenient program called KDE Connect to interface a Linux/KDE computer with an Android device. It uses UDP broadcast. And it worked fine when my wifi was not encrypted.
I recently had to change and use WPA encryption, and since then the app cannot connect, even after clearing the settings and trying again.

Is it likely that WPA is somehow blocking the UDP broadcast ? And if so what can I do about it ?

Comment: I've run some tests using UDP broadcast from Android to that PC (which is on the same wifi) and another one which is on ethernet connected to the wifi router. The latter receives the UDP packets, not the first one. I have neither iptable nor ufw. What can I check to know what is blocking incoming UDP ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was wrong, but no communication between any device connected to this wifi hotspot was possible (not only UDP, but also ping, ssh...). To and from the outside, yes. So I reset it and updated the firmware, and the problem is gone.